# TableView only loading contents of one cell as I scroll

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiview

I'm loading UIViews into my tableview cells content view but as I scroll through my tableview, only one cell loads its view. Its loading the correct view for each cell but it only loads one and then disappears as a new cell appears from the bottom. All of the data is loaded locally via a function `makeTableViewRowView` (an array of strings that populates the uiview).

```
 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: expenseCell, for: indexPath)
        tableViewRow = makeTableViewRowView(indexPath: indexPath)
        tableViewRow.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        cell.contentView.addSubview(tableViewRow)
        cell.selectionStyle = .none

        let margins = cell.contentView.layoutMarginsGuide
        tableViewRow.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margins.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        tableViewRow.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margins.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        tableViewRow.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margins.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        tableViewRow.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40).isActive = true
        return cell
    }
```

[image: broken tableView]

Comment: What is `tableViewRow`?

Comment: @Mr.Bista It's just a property that holds the UIView cause makeTableViewRowView returns a UIView

Comment: its because `tableViewRow` is initialised only once, thats why its present at the last cell only

Comment: try using a custom cell, instead of adding subview in `cellForRowAt`

Comment: @HamzaAnsari yep. that did it.

Answer (score 0):

make custom cell in interface builder and `deque` it. And make changes as per requirement for that cell in  `cellForRowAtIndexPath`! Because `cellForRowAtIndexPath` will get called when your cell will be `deque`, I mean cell will be reused! So, creating view in `cellforrow` and add it as subview is not good solution, you can add directly from interface builder and can manipulate it in  `cellforrow` as per requirement!

Comment: Good thought but I'm not using IB for this project. Hamza's answer worked for me.